# How to update a column value with the current column value plus an increment in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to to update a column value with the current column value plus an increment. My table structure is as follows:

```
id   |   menu   | priority
__________________________

 1   |   One    |   2
 2   |   Two    |   3
 3   |   Three  |   1
```

A simple query I have tried that is working:

```
update table set priority=priority+1 where id=2
```

in codeigniter:

```
$update_new_pri=$this->db->where('id',$menu_ids[$i])->update($this->table['menu'],array('menu_priority'=>'menu_priority+1'));
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

> You may also use the $this->db->set() function when performing
>   updates to the database.

```
$this->db->where('id',$menu_ids[$i])
     ->set('menu_priority', 'menu_priority+1', FALSE)      
     ->update($this->table['menu']);
```

> set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that
>   will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE. To illustrate
>   the difference, here is set() used both with and without the escape
>   parameter.

Comment: Can I use multiple `set()` in the same update in active record?

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?