# CI update_batch; Concatenate and increment variable and string as array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, sql-update

Using CI `update_batch()`, I am unable to set a value where I increment an integer db value.  This works successfully with CI `set(); update()`, but batch is the better option as there are multiple updates.

I have columns that all have the same characters at the end of the name, with different characters at the beginning (different years):  2014x , 2015x , 2016x , etc.
So I have created a `$var` that identifies the year, then I add the string `'x' and 'y'` via concatenation.  Finally, the value setting in the array is to increment by 1 so I add +1 .  This concatenation works fine in the keys - that is to say I am updating the correct column and fields.

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => $name1,
            $var.'x' => $var.'x+1'),
    array('name' => $name2,
            $var.'y' => $var.'y+1')
            );          
$this->db->update_batch('my_table', $data, 'tname');
```

In the above case, the fields are updated with the value of only `$var` - the year that has been defined.

I have also tried the following:

```
=> '{"$var.x+1"}'  // places a '0' value in the field
=> $var.'x' +1       // places the value of $var
=> '$var.x+1'        // places a '0' value in the field
```

How can I use `update_batch()` to increment my field by `1`?

As an example, this code works successfully:

```
$this->db->where('name',$name1);
$this->db->set($var.'x',$var.'x+1',FALSE);
$this->db->update('my_table');
```

Comment: this is kind of confusing. What is your expected output? if `$var = 2015` would  your first array be: `array(
                '2015x' => '2016x'
            )` ?

Comment: 2015x is the column.  I want the value in 2015x to be incremented by 1, so 2015x+1.

Comment: so your final array would be `array( '2015x' => '2015x+1' )` ? Thats not an increment (since youre not adding numbers), that is just concatenation.

Comment: https://eval.in/411994 - what is wrong?

Comment: i have edited the question to include the update code that works.  I want to make it work with update_batch

Comment: @splash58 - the issue is that the db field is not incrementing.  rather the field is either being updated with the value of $var or just 0, depending on the couple of things I've tried.  please see the 2nd code block in my question

Comment: this is probably because of the type of column you have in your database. What is it set for? VARCHAR, TEXT, INT ? and why do you say "incrementing"? your value is a string like this: `"2015x+1"`

Comment: @CodeGodie - the column type is int

Comment: if the type is INT, and you are trying to update it to `"2015x+1"` , it will not work, as this is a string. What do you want your value to be?

Comment: 2015x is a column.  I want the current value in the column to be incremented by 1.  If the current value is 10, this update should make it 11.  If the current value is 100, the update should make it 101.

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664910/how-to-update-a-column-value-with-the-current-column-value-plus-an-increment-in

Comment: there is a method which print the query string, i forget it's name. Maybу, you call it to show the query?

Comment: @splash58 - fyi, here is the query:    UPDATE `my_table` 
SET `2014x` = CASE WHEN `name` = 'name1' THEN '2014x +1' ELSE `2014x` END,
`2014y` = CASE WHEN `name` = 'name2' THEN '2014y +1' ELSE `2014y` END
WHERE `name` IN ('name1','name2')

Comment: remove quotes here - `'2014x +1' `

Comment: That makes sense for a sql cli, but CI adds the quotes, so not sure how I would do that and still use update_batch?  And I think that goes back to zairwolf's answer below about automatically escaped queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this via update_batch.

In the document https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html, its said like this:

> Note: All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.

how about just repeat db->set? e.g.

```
$this->db->where('name',$name1);
for($var = 2004; $var<2008;$var++) {
   $this->db->set($var.'x',$var.'x+1',FALSE);
   $this->db->set($var.'y',$var.'y+1',FALSE);
}
$this->db->update('my_table');
```

Comment: But the same is true of $this->db->update, where virtually the same syntax works

Comment: @edoras for db->update you can use db->set which support the 3rd parameter. but db->update_batch can't

Comment: so the 'FALSE' prevents the escaping?

Comment: @edoras yes. so why just simply repeat db->set to set your fields and then update it?

Comment: I originally did that, but thought batch would be less costly.  Looks like I have no choice now - thanks for the clarification / education on escaping!

Comment: @edoras you are most welcome. I think it won't cost that much, as before you run db->update, it wont affect the database.

Comment: fyi, just checked this as the correct answer and upvoted it.  I used update() alone and it worked just fine

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?